# Sending UTF-8 encoded emails with Python3 gives UnicodeEncodeError

Tags: python, email, python-3.x, encoding, smtplib

I am expecting the following code to send an UTF-8 encoded mail.

```
import email.parser
import smtplib

msg_str = """From: A <a@example.org>
To: B <b@example.org>
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="UTF-8"

Testing UTF-8: – ä."""

msg = email.parser.Parser().parsestr(msg_str)
smtplib.SMTP('localhost').send_message(msg)
```

However, I am getting this error.

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\u2013' in position 15: ordinal not in range(128)
```

What is failing here is the `flatten` call to `email.generator.BytesGenerator` in pythons `smtplib`. Shouldn't the email parser fail in the first place if the `msg` object can't be converted to bytes?

Comment: [Similar](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69379515/5320906).