# Problem with a mail message created by a parser

Tags: python, email, character-encoding

If I create a message this way (using real addresses, of course):

```
msg = email.message.EmailMessage()
msg['From'] = "sender@example.com"  
msg['To'] = "recipient@example.com" 
msg['Subject'] = "Ayons asperges pour le déjeuner"
msg.set_content("Cela ressemble à un excellent recipie déjeuner.")
```

I can successfully send it using `smtplib`. No problem with the Unicode characters in the body. The received message has these headers:

```
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="utf-8"
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable
```

---

If I try to create the same message in this alternative way:

```
msgsource = """\
From: sender@example.com
To: recipient@example.com
Subject: Ayons asperges pour le déjeuner

Cela ressemble à un excellent recipie déjeuner.
"""

msg = email.parser.Parser(policy=email.policy.default).parsestr(msgsource)
```

I can't send it. `send_message()` from `smtplib` fails with

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\xe0' in position 15: ordinal not in range(128)
```

and obviously expects ascii, not Unicode. What causes the difference and how to fix it properly?

(code is based on these [examples](https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.examples.html))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error can be avoided by encoding `msgsource` and then parsing the resulting bytes:

```py
msgsource = msgsource.encode('utf-8')
msg = email.message_from_bytes(msgsource, policy=policy.default)
print(msg)
```

outputs

```
From: sender@example.com
To: recipient@example.com
Subject: Ayons asperges pour le =?unknown-8bit?q?d=C3=A9jeuner?=

Cela ressemble �� un excellent recipie d��jeuner.
```

sending it to Python's SMTP DebuggingServer produces

```
b'From: sender@example.com'
b'To: recipient@example.com'
b'Subject: Ayons asperges pour le d\xc3\xa9jeuner'
b'X-Peer: ::1'
b''
b'Cela ressemble \xc3\xa0 un excellent recipie d\xc3\xa9jeuner.'
```

Note that no encoding headers are written: I'm guessing that the parsers attempt to reproduce the message from the source string or bytes as faithfully as possible, making as few additional assumptions as possible.  The Parser [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.parser.html#parser-api)

> [Parser is] an API that can be used to parse a message when the complete contents of the message are available in a [string/bytes/file]

seem to me to support this interpretation.

Comment: After reading the documentation about parsers and their counterparts the generators again, I now think the parser's input should be a message as found in a mailbox, i.e. already delivered. My expectation that it is an alternative way for creating a new message to be sent was probably wrong. Your answer seconds that.

Comment: Yes - I think it's a case of "you get what you give" (or possibly, Garbage In, Garbage Out).